# I want to use JavascriptAPI of OrientDB, but

Tags: javascript, html, orientdb

I want to use JavascriptAPI of OrientDB.
However, orientdb-api.js is not found.
ex)https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/master/server/src/site/js/orientdb-api.js
Where will it be?
In addition, how should I describe it to use a JavaScript in HTML?

Answer (score 1):

In according with the documentation Javascript API has been deprecated: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Javascript-Driver.html

If want, you can try this: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-js whichin is written this: 'New Javascript driver for OrientDB with a Blueprints/Gremlin like syntax. This library was an experiment and hasn't been maintained for long time. If you're using Node.js, we suggest to use https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientjs instead'.

Hope it helps.

Regards